# Is there a function that returns the root letter for special chars?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

in .NET is there a function that returns the root letter (the letter without special attributes like cedilla), kinda:

```
Select Case c
  Case "á", "à", "ã", "â", "ä", "ª" : x = "a"
  Case "é", "è", "ê", "ë" : x = "e"
  Case "í", "ì", "î", "ï" : x = "i"
  Case "ó", "ò", "õ", "ô", "ö", "º" : x = "o"
  Case "ú", "ù", "û", "ü" : x = "u"

  Case "Á", "À", "Ã", "Â", "Ä" : x = "A"
  Case "É", "È", "Ê", "Ë" : x = "E"
  Case "Í", "Ì", "Î", "Ï" : x = "I"
  Case "Ó", "Ò", "Õ", "Ô", "Ö" : x = "O"
  Case "Ú", "Ù", "Û", "Ü" : x = "U"

  Case "ç" : x = "c"
  Case "Ç" : x = "C"

  Case Else
       x = c
End Select
```

This code miss some letters, but it's only for the example sake :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if this works out for you:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2006/10/30/removing-diacritics-accents-from-strings.aspx

Answer (score 2):

By the way (completely unrelated to the question), your code operates on strings. This isn't only less efficient, it actually doesn't really make sense since you're interested in individual **characters** rather than strings, and these are distinct data types in .NET.

To get a single-character literal rather than a string literal, append `c` to your literal:

```
Select Case c
  Case "á"c, "à"c, "ã"c, "â"c, "ä"c, "ª"c : x = "a"c
  ' … and so on. '
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

taken from Chetan Sastry response, here I give you the VB.NET code and the C# one copied from his GREAT answer :)

VB:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Globalization

''' <summary>
''' Removes the special attributes of the letters passed in the word
''' </summary>
''' <param name="word">Word to be normalized</param>
Function RemoveDiacritics(ByRef word As String) As String
    Dim normalizedString As String = word.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
    Dim r As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Char

    For i = 0 To i < normalizedString.Length
        c = normalizedString(i)
        If (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) <> UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) Then
            r.Append(c)
        End If
    Next

    RemoveDiacritics = r.ToString
End Function
```

C#

```
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

/// <summary>
/// Removes the special attributes of the letters passed in the word
/// </summary>
/// <param name="word">Word to be normalized</param>
public String RemoveDiacritics(String word)
{
  String normalizedString = word.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  int i;
  Char c;

  for (i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
  {
    c = normalizedString[i];
    if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
  stringBuilder.Append(c);
  }

  return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

I hope it helps someone like me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is as simple method compare string in .NET

```
public static string NormalizeString(string value)
{
    string nameFormatted = value.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKD);
    Regex reg = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]");
    return reg.Replace(nameFormatted, "");
}
```